# how to create a back button in the footer (ionic framework)?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic and want to create a back button in the footer. Here's how I'm doing it.

My view:

```
  <div class="bar bar-footer bar-dark">
    <button class="button button-outline button-light" ng-click="goBack()"><i class="ion-arrow-left-c"></i> Back</button>
  </div>
```

and the controller for this view:

```
$scope.goBack = function () {
    window.history.back();
};
```

My question: is there a better way of doing this (i.e. a directive), or is this how you are doing this also?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With custom click action, using $ionicNavBarDelegate:

```
<button class="button" ng-click="goBack()">Back</button>

function MyCtrl($scope, $ionicNavBarDelegate) {
  $scope.goBack = function() {
    $ionicNavBarDelegate.back();
  };
}
```

From the ionic docs:
http://ionicframework.com/docs/nightly/api/directive/ionNavBackButton/

Comment: Thank you for answering!  I did see that. However, my understanding is that the ion-nav-bar is a top-of-page navigation control, similar to a header & it cannot be embedded in a footer.

Comment: You're right.  Sorry, I should have been more clear.  Use ng-click on your back button to call a function that includes $ionicNavBarDelegate.back() like the example above.  I'll edit the example and remove the ion-nav-bar for clarity.

Comment: what is canGoBack here? I would only want to show the back button if you can go back as ut happens with ion-nav-back-button

Comment: where you able to show back button on footer bar when it can go back?

Comment: @NiravGandhi  
where you able to show back button on footer bar when it can go back as in ionic ?

Comment: @TomKrones What is canGoback?How to display the button only when go back in ionic?

Comment: @Ankita it doesn't have anything to do with this quest.  I removed it.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: This is now deprecated and causes a warning. The preferred method is `$ionicHistory.goBack();`

Answer (score 8):

Use the `$ionicGoBack` function as the click handler

```
<button class="button" ng-click="$ionicGoBack()">Back</button>
```

Answer (score 6):

You could also just use:

```
$ionicHistory.goBack();
```